# How to replace a substring within an attribute JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, replace, substring

For the last few hours I have scoured for a way to do this and have com up with nothing. I am trying to figure out a way to change only a sub string within an attribute. An example of what I would like to do is change

```
<a href="media/gallery/jtnp/JT.JPG" rel="shadowbox[JTNP]" title="Joshua tree" class="shaddowimages"><img id="JTth" src="media/gallery/jtnp/b_thum/JTthumb.JPG" alt="A small Joshua tree"></a>
```

to

```
<a href="media/gallery/jtnp/JT.JPG" rel="shadowbox[JTNP]" title="Joshua tree" class="shaddowimages"><img id="JTth" src="media/gallery/jtnp/s_thum/JTthumb.JPG" alt="A small Joshua tree"></a>
```

Here is what I have so far, however nothing happens when I attempt to press the button #changethumb.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var count = 0;

    $('#changethumb').click(function() {

        if (count === 0) {
            $('#shaddowimages img').each(function() {
                $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('b_', 's_'));
            });
            count = 1;
        } else {
            $('#shaddowimages img').each(function() {
            $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('s_', 'b_'));    
            });
        count = 0;
        }
    })
});
```

I could go through and replace each src manually, but having 20+ images, I would like a way to automate this if I could. Any help?

Comment: its a class ".shaddowimages" not id.

Comment: Wow. now I feel like such a moron. Thank you for pointing out what my eyes could not see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.attr( attributeName, function(index, attr) )](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr)

```
$('#shaddowimages img').attr('src', function (i, old) {
    return old.replace('b_', 's_');
});
```

or Better use [.prop( propertyName, function(index, oldPropertyValue) )](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-functionindex--oldPropertyValue)

```
$('#shaddowimages img').prop('src', function (i, old) {
    return old.replace('b_', 's_');
});
```

Read [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: This reply made the most sense to me, Thank you for providing links to other reading, that really helps explain this to me.

Answer (score 0):

Can run all your logic within `attr` so you don't have to duplicate code in your `'if`

```
 $('#changethumb').click(function() {
    $('#shaddowimages img').attr('src', function (i, src) {
         var newSrc= count==1 ? src.replace('b_', 's_') : src.replace('s_', 'b_');
         count=  count == 1 ? 10 : 1;
          return  newSrc;
    });
 });
```

Seems strange that `count` is only 1 or 10. Copied your code but it doesn't make sense

Comment: I changed the 1 and 10. It made sense to my overtired head, but 0 and 1 are much cleaner to read.